# JavaScript Date returns different values when the components are separated

Tags: javascript, ionic2, momentjs

I have a date that I want converted to a number in the format of yyyymmdd.
it comes in as

```
2017-08-16T05:47:42.070Z
```

I convert it as

```
let dt  = new Date(dte)
```

which creates the date in dt of:

```
Wed Aug 16 2017 15:47:42 GMT+1000 (E. Australia Standard Time)
```

Now when I look at the parts I get the following:

```
dt.getFullYear() = 2017
dt.getMonth() = 7
dt.getDay() = 3
```

How come the  day and month are off?

Answer (score 1):

`getMonth()`

returns an integer number, between 0 and 11, representing the month in the given date according to local time. 0 corresponds to January, 1 to February, and so on.

---

`getDay()`

returns an integer number corresponding to the day of the week for the given date, according to local time: 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, and so on.

---

This means that result of your code is correct

```
dt.getFullYear() = 2017
dt.getMonth() = 7
dt.getDay() = 3
```

There is a function called `getDate()` that will return `16` for your case.

These functions are from native javascript Date Object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}

console.log(formatDate("2017-08-16T05:47:42.070Z"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code return result for you:

```js
var dte = '2017-08-16T05:47:42.070Z';
var dt  = new Date(dte);

var myFrmt = dt.getFullYear().toString() + (dt.getMonth()+1).toString() + dt.getDate().toString();

alert(myFrmt);
```

Answer (score -1):

Found out an easy way (don't know why the above doesn't work!!) using Moment

```
Moment(dt).format('YYYYMMDD').toString()
```

gives the answer: 20170816 !!

Comment: You did not mention in your question that you can use momentjs. Also question is about something else, as far as i understand it is about why getDay() and getMonth() are not the same from the date string.

Comment: That is correct...I'm trying to get a result and if I can't get one with the tools I'm using then I'll use another tool. The problem still exists with the first question and result has been obtained with the second comment. Sorry that I did not explain the result I was after in my first question.